# Symfony 2 DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource() error

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony 2 and I have a working webpage on my computer. The problem is that when I upload it to the production server I receive the following error:

```
    ErrorException: Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource() [domdocument.schemavalidatesource]: Invalid Schema in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 363

    in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php line 67
    at ErrorHandler->handle()
    at DOMDocument->schemaValidateSource() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 363
    at XmlFileLoader->validateSchema() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 293
    at XmlFileLoader->validate() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 222
    at XmlFileLoader->parseFile() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 40
    at XmlFileLoader->load() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php line 43
    at FrameworkExtension->load() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 42
    at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
    at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php line 119
    at Compiler->compile() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php line 437
    at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 872
    at Kernel->buildContainer() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 783
    at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 517
    at Kernel->boot() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 548
    at Kernel->handle() in /home/ljrgwoej/public_html/webs/Chambalo/web/app.php line 12
```

what could I do? i have google a lot with no results. Thanks

Comment: You could post some code and specify when exactly the error occurs. You should also compare your dev machine with your prod machine and check if you done all steps on your prod machine.

Comment: which code would you need? i have no idea where the error could be.

Comment: the webpage work well in prod enviroment on localhost.

Comment: the error occurs when loading the page, with every page.

Comment: check php versions , php extensions etc ... delete cache files ...

Comment: I have deleted cache file with no results, php versions and extension are not a problem because I have other symfony proyects working well on the server.

Comment: post your modified xml files (config, services, etc.) or try to debug it and find out on which xml document the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I got this after I did an update. I fixed this by downgrading my version of libxml from libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2 to libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1.

yum downgrade libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1